# Como cambiar el background-image: linear-gradient de mi body por otro background-image: linear-gradient con html, css y js y un elemento <a>

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, gradient

Como cambiar mi

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #434343 0%, black 100%);
```

por un

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #eeeeee, #dddddd, #cccccc, #bbbbbb);
```

en html, css, y js con un elemento `<a>`.

como si fuese de un "Modo Oscuro" a un "Modo Claro"

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Gracias Ruslan por editarla !

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, que condiciones gatillan el cambio?

Answer (score 0):

Yo me imagino que la pregunta se refiere a cambiarlo de modo dinamico, esto lo puedes lograr utilizando JS y referenciando bien los css.

Aqui te dejo el codigo para que alternes de Claro a Oscuro segun tu ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Cambio de Modo</title>
<style>
body {
    transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.modo-oscuro {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #434343 0%, black 100%);
    color: white;
}

.modo-claro {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #eeeeee, #dddddd, #cccccc, #bbbbbb);
    color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="modo-toggle">Cambiar Modo</a>
    <div class="modo-claro" id="contenido">
    <h2>Esto es una prueba</h2>
    <h3>Cambio de claro a oscuro</h3>
    <h3>presiona el boton</h3>
  </div>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const modoToggle = document.getElementById("modo-toggle");
    const contenido = document.getElementById("contenido");

    modoToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
        contenido.classList.toggle("modo-oscuro");
        contenido.classList.toggle("modo-claro");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```